# Image title appears in separate div on hover

Tags: jquery, image, hover, title

I am very new to jQuery, so I would appreciate any help/advice you can offer!

I got this to work in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cakeeater/LUAtb/10/

Basically, I just need the title of the image to replace the "Hello" text when you hover over the image.

```
jQuery().ready(function() { 
jQuery("#caption").text('Hello'); });
jQuery('img.gallery').mouseenter(function() { 
   var title = $(this).attr("title");
jQuery("#caption").text(title); });
jQuery('img.gallery').mouseleave(function() { 
jQuery("#caption").text('Hello'); });
```

However, when I put it into the site, the "Hello" text is the only function that works – and the image titles do not show up on hover: http://bit.ly/MNgdUS

I'm sure there probably a better way to write the script... I don't see any errors in Firebug and I also tried disabling all other scripts on the site with the same results. Any ideas?

Comment: The link to your site is broken; please fix it.

Comment: Or better, provide the code in question so we can see it without clicking a link, and so future users can also see it even after you've uploaded a fix.

Comment: Sorry about that, added the code and fixed the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(function() {
    "use strict";
    $("#gallerydescription").text("Hello");
    $("img.team").hover(
        function() {
            $("#gallerydescription").text($(this).attr("alt"));
        },
        function() {
            $("#gallerydescription").text("Goodbye");
        }
    );
});
```

using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element.
>
> Calling `$(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)` is shorthand for:
>
> `$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`

Comment: WORKS PERFECTLY!! Thanks for your reply and the explanation of .hover – starting to understand a little better. Very appreciated!!!! :)